# Access 2007 & 2003 : Creating an mde for 2003 users with a 2007 dev copy issues

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, compatibility

So i have an image on my computer that has office 2007, and I have the development copy of this database file where I corrected some code, added some fields, etc...

I then converted the Access file (.mdb dev file) to Access 2002-2003 format to create an mde. So I then created the new mde, but when users try to open, it gives them the message that it is not the correct format and that they should upgrade to a newer version of access.

So will i be able to get this done with having office 2007, and these other end users not having their new image pushed yet (so they still have office 2003)? I thought that if I converted the file to 2002-2003 then this should not be a problem>

Thanks 
Justin

Comment: Are you sure all users are running Office 2003?  If they have Access 2000 or Access XP/2002 installed they will not be able to open an MDE created in Access 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the MDE in the lowest version of Access involved, it should be usable by all later versions. The format of the MDB file (A2000, A2002/2003, A2007) is separate from the version of Access, as what's relevant to the MDE is which version of VBA is executing the compiled p-code in the MDE. An A2000-format file compiled in A2007 won't run on A2000, for instance, but if compiled in A2000, should be runnable ay A2000, A2002, A2003, A2007 and A2010.

But I'm not entirely certain about this. It could be there's a break from A2003 to A2007/2010. Also, I don't use MDEs that much, and not at all in mixed deployment environments.

Comment: @David....so you pretty much answered my question David. What you are saying makes sense....I was actually trying to do the reverse in a sense. Orginally the file was a 02-03 version, that I copied the MDB dev copy to a new laptop with a new image that include the 2007 office upgrade. When i opened the access files that I have i noticed it was defaulting everything to the .accdb (or whatever). I used the ribbon > manage > convert to 2002-2003 version just to make sure that it retained the right type. however, after i compile a new .mde (and the file ext is .mde) the user that do not have the

Comment: ....new image yet are getting the error message "File format not correct.upgrade to a new version of access..." so i was just thinking there was something i was missing. thanks man

Comment: Have you installed Office 2003 SP3?  I vaguely recall a difference in MDE format somewhere in there.